# Sending mutlitple requests of httplib, raising traceback exceptions

Tags: python, django, httplib

Here is the code:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("127.0.0.1:8000")
conn.request("POST", "/api/job/", some_params, headers)
conn.close()
```

no problem with sending request to server

but if i use loop for example:

```
for i in range(n):
   conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("127.0.0.1:8000")
   conn.request("POST", "/api/job/", some_params, headers)
   conn.close()
```

it rises an exception, but it is interesting that request is successfull:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 284, in run
self.finish_response()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 324, in finish_response
self.write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 403, in write
self.send_headers()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 467, in send_headers
self.send_preamble()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 385, in send_preamble
'Date: %s\r\n' % http_date()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
self.flush()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 60438)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
self.process_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 570, in __init__
BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
self.finish()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
self.wfile.flush()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
```

any suggestions ???

Comment: Is just the first request successfully in the loop?? or aare all the requests? are you using a single threaded dev server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like your buffer is getting filled. Your buffer will fill with any network requests you make, then is cleared when the server acknowledges receipt of the data. Not sure if there isn't a better way to do this, but you could try giving the server some time to acknowledge receipt by doing a short `time.pause` within your loop.